# what is an A record and how it is related to DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, a-record

i dont know what A records do.

and are they necessary for a web server to host multiple domains and how are they related to DNS?

Comment: +1 because I'm not a fan of "browse-by vote-downs." Most likely they voted you down because you can look at a variety of direct answers to this with a simple Google search. - The Question if they are necessary for multiple domains is however relevant and fairly original.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `A` record *is* a DNS record.

Specifically it's the DNS record that maps from a hostname to an IP address.  Every URL that contains a domain name must go via an A record to find the IP address of the server that's hosting it.

See [RFC 1034](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=1034) and [RFC 1035](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=1035).

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a loaded question, but I'll try to give a brief conceptual description. An A record is a translation of a Domain name to an IP address. When a computer queries out to find a domain (google.com, yahoo.com, etc), it doesn't find it by the domain, but the IP; the DNS server gives the IP that it has in the A record when it receives the query for the domain and the computer then navigates to that address. It is of course a lot more complicated than that, but that is a high level description of what service an A record performs.

Answer (score 0):

a quick example

your-domain.org.  IN    A   123.456.789.012 ;this is the public ip